# SQL - select top 10 rows with the highest number (counted)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi I have a database full of records of players and theirs match Stats.

Example:

[image: Database example]

( number means goals scored in match )

What I'm, trying to do is, select top X players that scores most of goals in Season.

I'm trying something like this, but I think there must be another Select with select count (number) or something.

```
  SELECT TOP 10 [playerID]
      ,[number]
      ,[league]
      ,[yearID]
      ,[YellowCard]
      ,[RedCard]
  FROM [ms4033].[dbo].[Shooter]
  where yearID=28 AND league=4
  group by playerID
```

Thanks for your time :-)

Comment: Since the OP didn't mention which version of SQL he was asking about, it might be worth noting for future researchers that TOP is only supported in Transact-SQL/Sybase.  The ANSI version (not supported by SQL Server) is FETCH FIRST x ROWS ONLY, after the select statement, while MySql and PostGres use LIMIT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `SUM` number field and order by it like this;

```
 SELECT TOP 10 
      playerID, 
      SUM([number]) as goals,
      [league],
      [yearID],
      SUM([YellowCard]) as YellowCards,
      SUM([RedCard]) as RedCards,
  FROM [ms4033].[dbo].[Shooter]
  WHERE yearID=28 AND league=4
  GROUP BY playerID, league, yearID
  ORDER BY goals DESC
```

Comment: Thanks, Easy and good-looking :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
select top 10 
 t.[playerID]
,t.totalgoals
,s.[league]
,s.[yearID]
,s.[YellowCard]
,s.[RedCard] from (
SELECT -- TOP 10 
   [playerID]
  ,sum([number]) as totalgoals
  ,[league]
  ,[yearID]
  -- ,[YellowCard]
  -- ,[RedCard]
FROM [ms4033].[dbo].[Shooter]
where yearID=28 AND league=4
group by playerID,[league],[yearID]) t
join [ms4033].[dbo].[Shooter] s on t.playerid = s.playerid
order by totalgoals desc
```

You can do the calculation for total goals in the inner query and order it to select the top 10 players.

Comment: Yes, exactly this. Output are the same 10 top rows (Top Shooter 10times) But I'll corect it by myself. Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: What is the purpose of the subquery?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

```
 SELECT TOP 10 [playerID]
      ,count([number])
  FROM [ms4033].[dbo].[Shooter]
  where yearID=28 AND league=4
  group by playerID
  Order by count(number) desc
```